Existence of High Dimensional Central Limit Theorem
Given a sequence of $n$ i.i.d. random vector $\{\mathbf{X}_{i}\}_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, with covariance matrix $\mathbf{I}_{d \times d}$, and considering that the dimension $d$ is a linear function of (or proportional to) sample size $n$, can we make any assertions about the convergence of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}$ or $\mathbb{P} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i} \in A \right)$?
In my review of several papers, the most advanced result I found pertains to cases where $A$ is a rectangle, for example this.
I am curious if there are any related or more advanced results we can discuss. Specifically, is there any guarantee that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbf{X}_{i}$ converges to some distribution (possibly without a closed form)? Please feel free to edit my question, include any related materials, or impose any additional assumptions on my questions.
